# Algorithm caption left alignment

Tags: captions, algorithms, alignment, algorithm2e

I am struggling with moving the caption's location to the left.
Is there a way to fix the alignment of the caption in the algorithm?

Below are some of the packages that I used and the code.

Thanks.

```
\usepackage[ruled, lined, linesnumbered, commentsnumbered, resetcount, longend]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Offine Algorithm}\label{alg:offline}
\SetKwFunction{Send}{Send}
\SetKwFunction{Receive}{Receive}
\SetKwFunction{Verify}{Verify}
\SetKwFunction{Broadcast}{Broadcast}
\SetKwFunction{Store}{Store}
\SetKwInOut{KwIn}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{KwOut}{Output}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...

Comment: Welcome to TeX! I added the line `\SetAlCapHSkip{0ex}` right before `\caption`, and it removed the space. Can you try this out?

Comment: Algorithm2e uses a custom caption.  If you search here for "algorithm2e caption" you will find several questions, but I don't really understand the solutions.

Comment: Thank you all so much for the comments.
I tried \SetAlCapHSkip{0ex} and it really helped!

Comment: @juneshin, did you try adding the line `\SetAlCapHSkip{0ex}` before `\caption{Offine Algorithm}\label{alg:offline}`? Did it solve the issue? Please let us know. Thank you!

Comment: @juneshin, this is great! With your permission, I will write about this solution as an answer below. Thank you so much for letting us know! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## A solution that worked

Add the code line:

```
\SetAlCapHSkip{0ex}
```

right before

```
\caption{Offine Algorithm}\label{alg:offline}
```

in your code to remove the horizontal space before the caption.

The full code example is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled, lined, linesnumbered, commentsnumbered, resetcount, longend]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\SetAlCapHSkip{0ex} % <----------------- This is the line you should add.
\caption{Offine Algorithm}\label{alg:offline}
\SetKwFunction{Send}{Send}
\SetKwFunction{Receive}{Receive}
\SetKwFunction{Verify}{Verify}
\SetKwFunction{Broadcast}{Broadcast}
\SetKwFunction{Store}{Store}
\SetKwInOut{KwIn}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{KwOut}{Output}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

After you compile and run the code, it will look like this:
[image]

### Sources

This solution is taken from page 23 of the `algorithm2e` package documentation, which you can find at https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf or access through https://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e?lang=en.

On this page, it says that

> `\SetAlCapHSkip{length}` sets the horizontal skip before Algorithm: in caption when used in ruled algorithm.

You might find some additional useful macros there to boost your project.

**Good luck!**

Comment: This has nothing to do with the answer itself, save for saying that this is a very well written answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Astrid!